# Recover data from Postgresql database after failed system update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, database, postgresql

First, I want to make clear that this question [was already asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911850/recover-data-from-postgresql-database-after-ubuntu-stopped-working) in askubuntu, but I proceeded to delete it because I got almost no feedback. If this violates SU protocol, please let me know.

---

Welcome to my mess...

The situation is:

- Ubuntu Software was making some "important" updates (and probably a lot of them, since was easily more than 9 months since my last update).
- The update seemed to stop working (update progress bar frozen), with no explanation of what was happening. There is a notification of some error that didn't give me much information or anything to do about it, save for clicking on the "Report" button.
- After around 8 hours of using the PC and hoping that the issue would resolve itself, I note that the process bar is still frozen. I cross my fingers and shut down the computer.
- Now laptop doesn't boot on Ubuntu (Still has Windows, didn't try to boot that, but I guess it still works).
- Big and important Postgresql database is stored in laptop, on `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main` (yeah, I was really tired the day before when I shut down the laptop, didn't anticipate this... really stupid thing to do; don't do this at home kids).
- Made a bootable usb stick with Ubuntu 16.04 live, with the intention of accessing my files and make a backup, before re-installing Ubuntu.
- Can't backup mentioned database (meaning, can copy/paste the folder with Nautilus or via terminal+sudo), it says the contents of `/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main` are unreadable (I don't have permissions). With my home directory there are fewer problems and I manage to make a backup (with a couple of unimportant exceptions).

What can I do about this? Is it possible to copy the files from the database to make a backup? Furthermore, how can I access this database afterwards?

Thanks for your time...

---

**Update**: I succesfully backed up my files using `sudo /bin/bash` and then `cp`, as davidgo suggested (saved them into an external hard drive).

Then I installed ubuntu from scratch in my PC, installed posgresql-9.5 (adding
the Postgres PGDG repo mentioned by davidgo), and copied the files to the same
original location (using `cp -rnP /pathto/backupfolder /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main`) and changed the ownership to "postgres".

Now my problem is that I cannot start the postgresql client (`psql`). This is the command line output:

```
user@machine:~$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Looking up the documentation, I found that I could use `pg_ctl` to start the
server, but that in Ubuntu, is expected that I use `pg_ctlcluster` instead. Ok,
so I try this:

```
user@machine:~$ su - postgres
Password: 
postgres@machine:~$ pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 1034)
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf"
```

I am a rather clumsy PostgreSQL user, I can tell, so this is probably something
real simple that I cannot see right now. Again, any help would be more than
wecome!

Comment: I assume you don't have no backups of this important database?

Comment: No, I don't have a backup. I could rebuild it with enough time (a couple of weeks I think), but that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If you have no backups of the database nor any images of the system itself, you are sort of up the creek without a paddle.  If you already installed Ubuntu over your existing installation your data isn't going to be there. *If it says you don't have permissions you should give yourself permissions.*

Comment: At this point I still have my original Ubuntu installation (broken, but all the files are there). Regarding the permissions, I do not know how can I do that, since I can't boot from said original installation and postgresql client or the command line (Ubuntu recovery mode doesn't work either).

Comment: This is the time you thank God that you have a recent backup.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get this working, the steps would be:

1. Install a new copy of UBUNTU - onto a new drive, so as not to overwrite
   the postgres files.  Install Postgres 9.5 on the new instance (You may
   or may not need to add the [Postgres PGDG repo](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) to do this)
2. Copy the old Postgres files onto the new system to the same
   location (typically /var/lib/pgsql/9.5) .  As you are having
   difficulties here, you should try doing it AS ROOT from the command line.
   (I assume SELinux is not operative or interfering, if it is, disable it).
   [You can either put the disk in as a second drive, or use a USB enclosure]
   To get root access, type "sudo /bin/bash"
3. Change the ownership permissions of the postgresql files to the postgres
   user.
4. Start Postgres!

Comment: A little late, but thanks a lot! The trick with `sudo /bin/bash` was key to make a backup, but I have new problems now, described in the **update** part of my post. If you can check it and give me any suggestion I would be very grateful.

Comment: A couple of things - to run Postgres you gave 2 parts - launching the server and connecting to it with clients. psql is a client, and is complaining that it can't connect to the server.  I'm guessing pg_ctlcluster is doing this for you, but I have never used it - I prefer /etc/inot.d/postgres start (or similar) which automatically backgrounds it.  The thing is once Postgres is running, launch a running, launch psql in a second window.  If you have tried this and it is not working, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the shared_buffers was too big that cased the failed state, I decrease it to 128MB and restarted then worked fine , I made a copy of the data directory after an OS crash to a new OS  ..

Comment: Can you describe exactly how to do this?   What commands, etc.?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.